# Ruby on Rails - Not Select a Given Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I'm querying a table which has about 15 columns.  I only need 13 of those columns.  To make the query faster, is there a way to select all but those 2 columns I do not need? Something like:

```
My_table.select_all_but([:column_5, :column_8]).all
```

Comment: `My_table` is an unconventional class name.  `MyTable` would be the convention.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
My_table.select ( My_table.column_names - ['column_5', 'column_8'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pluck

```
    Person.pluck(:id, :name)
    # SELECT people.id, people.name FROM people
    # => [[1, 'David'], [2, 'Jeremy'], [3, 'Jose']]
```

Comment: @appLover is looking for **everything but** column 5 and column 8, not **only** column 5 and column 8.

Comment: You can pluck anything you want

Comment: To elaborate, I believe his requirement was not to allow for * except for two columns, rather to speed up his query on a set of known columns.  Ex: Something.pluck(:column_1, :column_2, :column_3, :column_4, :column_6, :column_7, :column_9, :column_10, :column_11, :column_12, :column_13, :column_14, :column_15)

Comment: I suppose his phrasing isn't 100% clear, but I believe he was looking to not have to write out all 13 columns, based on his example.

Comment: **Pluck and select are quite different.** ".. without loading a bunch of records .. Pluck returns an [nested] Array of attribute values".  It's not clear from the question if this is ok, or if the OP wants records.

Comment: To get "everything but" use the splat operator: `Person.pluck(*(My_table.column_names - ['column_5', 'column_8']))`